# Add an identifier row to a dataframe and then write to an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a row which identifies the dataframe inserted to the excel sheet.
Currently, I have my dataframe which looks like this-

```
Name Age Sal
John 23  19000
Amy  25  25000
Rock 22  19500
```

I want to write this dataframe to an excel sheet(I know i have to use pd.ExcelWriter) and add an extra identifier row at the start so that the final output in excel sheet looks like this

```
Employee Salary Database
Name Age Sal
John 23  19000
Amy  25  25000
Rock 22  19500
```

I don't know how to add this identifier row to the dataframe before the headers.Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter `startrow=1` for omit first row and write text to first cell, check also [Working with Cell Notation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow = 1, index=False)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

text = 'Employee Salary Database'
worksheet.write(0, 0, text)

writer.save()
```